# Super tiny editor font in TexMaker on an external monitor

Tags: texmaker

Why is the font in TexMaker super tiny on an external monitor? Like the pic below?

[image]

Edit: Control and scroll wheel did not work

Answer (score 2):

From the `Options` tab choose `Configure Texmaker` --> `Editor` --> `Editor Font Size` and set the font size to a large-enough value. (Note: The screenshots are from a previous version, however, for the current "ugly" version the process is unchanged.)

> [image]

Then:

> [image]